# WP 4.7 broke get_post_type or requires an explicit integer value?

Tags: custom-post-types

I just upgraded to WP 4.7, and suddenly code that uses get_post_type($id) stopped returning anything, and didn't throw an error either.

After trying a few things, I found that it would start working again if I changed my code from

```
get_post_type($id)
```

to

```
get_post_type(intval($id))
```

But I can't find anything in the docs about WP suddenly requiring explicit integer values. Anyone else seeing this?

**UPDATE**

So, using trim instead of intval works too.

```
get_post_type(trim($id))
```

And checking $id `(preg_match('/\s/',$id))` shows that it had a space. But oddly, this worked just fine in WP 4.6, so something must have changed to make that less forgiving in WP 4.7

Comment: What is the value in `$id` here? I tried passing both string and float values and they both worked fine for me.

Comment: I am having some terminology query issues as well. 4.7 has broke the categories on my site, and I need to figure out why and how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the devs at WP (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39164):

"This was an intentional change to get_post() in 4.7 - passing an invalid parameter may have previously returned a result, but it could've been an incorrect resource, for example, a value being cast to a numeric 1 and fetching from the incorrect post.
get_post( 123 ) is the same as get_post( '123' ) but not the same as get_post( " 123 " ) (Which now fails) IMHO, so I agree with the change, especially in this case."

So I would consider this the definitive answer. The behavior has changed to something better, it was just a surprise that it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is untrue. Let's fall down the rabbit hole...

First we call [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/)
Which calls [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) which if we're [not passing some sort of Object](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L519)
Calls [`WP_Post::get_instance()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/get_instance/) which does a conditional check to ensure whatever passed
 [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) which will return true for string "numbers".
Finally, it [converts the passed number to an integer](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L217) and returns it up the stack.

All of the above has shipped with WordPress 4.7 so whatever the issue is may be deeper than the built-in `get_post_type()` since it will accept both integers and "string integers".